# Google Sheets API, Python.HttpError 500 when requesting {url} returned "Internal error encountered.". Details: "Internal error encountered."

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Good afternoon. My client has a google spreadsheet that he made entries into via a telegram bot. But recently there was an error

```
<HttpError 500 when requesting returned "Internal error encountered.". Details: "Internal error encountered.">
```

Someone knows how to solve it? Do I need to change the code, or is this just a Google problem? I'm not attaching any code because I don't know what you need to provide. If anything, write, I'll show you the code you need

PS. The error occurs only when reading some sheet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a generic error that does not give us any insight on the problem, except for the obvious fact that there has been a problem accessing the website. There can be many solutions. Ill give you some generic ones.

- Refresh page
- Delete web browser cache
- Delete cookies

Reopen the page in a new web browser instance. Sorry for not providing an exact solutions. HTTPError 500 is extremely generic.

Comment: i use api access. I use Python